# Get column value that has combination of other column values across many rows

Tags: sql

I have to write a query that retrieves the list of "brand" that have a a combination of "name" and "id" equal to a specific value for both "name" and "id".

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| brand  | name  | id  |
+--------+-------+-----+
| brand1 | david | 123 |
| brand1 | john  | 456 |
| brand1 | adam  | 789 |
| brand2 | david | 123 |
| brand2 | stacy | 999 |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

For example, I want all brands that have rows that match

```
name = "david", id = 123 and 
name = "john", id = 456
```

In the table above, "brand1" has rows that have those two combinations of "name" and "id".

```
-- desired result
+--------+
| brand  |
+--------+
| brand1 |
+--------+
```

"Brand2" has "name = david, id = 123" but not "name = john, id = 456" so I dont want it.

Comment: I have done reformatting, if you don't like it feel free to roll it back

Comment: @deetee510 . . . Tag the question with the database being used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select brand
from t
where (name = 'david' and id = 123) or
      (name = 'john' and id = 456)
group by brand
having count(distinct name) = 2;
```

Comment: It has to be a little more generic. I take in a list of pairs of name and id. Right now its (david, 123) and (john, 456), but it can be any number of pairs of values.

Comment: I guess this SQL will not work as expected if he wanted the condition to be the same name with different ids e.g:`david=123 and david=999` they will be counted as 1 by `count(distinct name)`

Comment: to be fair @Accountantم if that would be the case or if the topicstarter wanted that he/she should had defined it in the question..

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland I understand, I just wanted to note that for the OP, and regarding the answer, I learn from every single answer Gordon writes on SO

Comment: I added my answer in a post below. Basically, to make it more generic to take in a list of name and id combinations, I concated the name and id column and check it against a list of desired name and ids concatenated strings.

Works similar to this suggested solution except I dont have to dynamically add multiple "or (name = ... and id = ...)" clauses. I just pass it in a list of already concatenated name and ids I want to check for.

Thanks for the solution Gordon. I built my answer after seeing your solution.

Comment: @Accountantم . . . The OP needs to be more specific about the database begin used and the data.  If the combinations are unique in each row, the OP can just use `count(*)`.  Some database support `count(distinct)` with multiple arguments.  Or some other work-around.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution. I created a pairs table with data like below:

```
david, 123
john, 456
```

Then the query becomes:

```
select t1.brand
from brand_table t1
join pairs t2 on t1.name = t2.name
and t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.brand
having count(distinct t1.name) = (select count(*) from pairs)
```

Comment: I kind of did the same thing except instead of a pairs table, I just concatenated name and id into one value to filter. Then I do the same thing in the "having" condition to make sure the brand has ALL pairs/concatenated strings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Gordons answer and modified it for my use.

```
select brand
from t
where concat(name,id) in (:nameIdConcatStringsList)
group by brand
having count(brand) = :sizeOf_nameIdConcatStringsList;
```

Basically, I created concatenated a list of strings of the name and id combinations I wanted. Example: (david123, john456)

I then find rows that the two columns concatenated equal the input list. Then I group and make sure that brand has a count equal to the size of the input list.

Answer (score -1):

Edit. I did not see the tag that this was supposed to be a sql question and assumed it to be related to pandas. My bad!! But instead of deleting it, I will let it be here, in case someone needs it to be implemented in pandas.
To select those with a  name and id belonging to a list

```
df[(df['brand'].isin(name_list)) & (df['id'].isin(id_list))]['brand']
```

For a particular name and id:

```
df[(df['brand']==name)& (df['id']==id)]['brand']
```

Comment: Using pandas only

Comment: what does this answer has to do with SQL?

Comment: Nothing, I did not see the tag and answered it. My bad!!